# Get all email adresses and send it on another email

Tags: javascript, asp.net

After send a postcard email I want to send an email to myself with the names of the people that the postcard was sent to.

Here's my code

```
count=0;
    if(!RS_Birthdays.EOF) {
        nome = String(RS_Aniversarios.Fields.Item("contact").Value);
        mailTo = String(RS_Aniversarios.Fields.Item("email").Value);
        mailSubject = "Happy Birthday" + (name != "" && nome != "null" ? " " + nome : "");
        SendCDOEmail(mailSubject,mailBody,"info@adasda.com",mailTo,mailCc, 1, "HTML");
        RS_Birthdays.MoveNext();
        Response.Write("Enviado: " + mailTo + "\n");
        count++;
    }
    SendCDOEmail("Anniversary sumary","The emails has been sent to: "+mailTo,"joni@sapo.pt","joni@sapo.pt","", 1, "HTML");
```

With this final line I could get email addresses from the sent emails (+mailTo) But I could I get all emails and print them on a email ?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to ask here, or what the `SendCDOEmail` method actually does. But you can iterate over a list of those that received the email and append the email addresses to the email body.

Answer (score 0):

Store all Email Addresses for which mails sending successful and concatenate all in one string or create html body and append in div or table.
set ishtmlbody to true and then call your SendCDOEmail method.

Answer (score 0):

Make an array:

```
count=0;
Array mailedTo = [];
if(!RS_Birthdays.EOF) {
    nome = String(RS_Aniversarios.Fields.Item("contact").Value);
    mailTo = String(RS_Aniversarios.Fields.Item("email").Value);
    mailSubject = "Happy Birthday" + (name != "" && nome != "null" ? " " + nome : "");
    SendCDOEmail(mailSubject,mailBody,"info@adasda.com",mailTo,mailCc, 1, "HTML");
    mailedTo.Add(mailTo)
    RS_Birthdays.MoveNext();
    Response.Write("Enviado: " + mailTo + "\n");
    count++;
}
string emails = mailedTo.ToString()
SendCDOEmail("Anniversary sumary","The emails has been sent to: "+emails,"joni@sapo.pt","joni@sapo.pt","", 1, "HTML");
```